# In general is $\frac{d\,\mu_1}{d\,\mu_2}\circ T = \frac{d\,T\mu_1}{d\,T\mu_2}$?

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Given an ergodic and non-singular dynamic system (definition provided [here](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/csilva/NonsingularET_Apr.pdf)) $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu_1, T)$ where $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu_1)$ is a measure space and $T$ is a fixed transformation, we then will have $\mu$ equivalent to $T\mu_1$ where $T\mu_1$ is defined by $T\mu_1(A)=\mu_1[T^{-1}(A)]$ for each $A\in \mathcal{B}$. Now suppose $\mu_2$ is another measure that is equivalent to $\mu_1$ and makes $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu_2, T)$ ergodic and non-singular. Hence, we will have $T\mu_2\sim\mu_2\sim\mu_1\sim T\mu_1$. Do we have:

$$
\frac{d\,\mu_1}{d\,\mu_2}\circ T = \frac{d\,T\mu_1}{d\,T\mu_2}
$$

$\mu_1$-almost everywhere? Here the "$\mu_1$-almost everywhere" can be replaced by "$\mu_2$-almost everywhere" or any one of those four measures. By definition of $T\mu_2$, for each $A\in\mathcal{B}$, we have:

$$
\int_X\chi_A(x)d\,T\mu_2 = \int_X\chi_A(Tx)d\,\mu_2
$$

I tried to show the following equation holds for each $A\in\mathcal{B}$ but cannot:

$$
\int_A\frac{d\,\mu_1}{d\,\mu_2}(x)d\,T\mu_2 = \int_A\frac{d\,\mu_1}{d\,\mu_2}\circ T(x)d\,\mu_2 = \int_A\frac{d\,T\mu_1}{d\,T\mu_2}(x)d\,\mu_2
$$

Any hints or counter-examples will be appreciated

Comment: Non-singular system?

Comment: My bad ... When there is only one transformation, I am used to calling it "non-singular system" instead of the common "non-singular transformation". The definition is the same

Comment: For every measurable $A$ you have $\int \mathbf{1}_A \circ T d\mu_2 = \int \mathbf{1}_A dT(\mu_2);$ therefore also when $\mathbf{1}_A$ is replaced by simple functions, monotone limits of simple functions and therefore integrable functions as well. Isn't this enough?

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks for your comment. I can only see your answer proved the first two terms in the last line are the same but cannot see how to bring that $T$ into the derivative. Do you mind provide more details?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4190415/169085

Comment: @AlpUzman Thanks. A solution was found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423728. In general, the "push-back" cannot be brought into a derivative so, in the post I shared, it is required that $T$ is at least right invertible but there might be some other conditions that could make it happen.

Comment: @SanaeKochiya Right. Note that the formula provided there is essentially the same formula I've provided in the discussion I've linked above. If one is content with conditioning on the pullback sigma algebra for the formula all that's needed is that $\mu_1$ is abs. cont. w/r/t $\mu_2$.